# How to broadcast a message from my own app to contacts on WhatsApp?

Tags: android, eclipse, whatsapp

Now i can send a message from my app to whatsapp by this shown code..BUT how to send to many contacts at one time

```
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String text = "Sorry For Interruption,I'm Just Trying Something";
            waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            if (waIntent != null) {
                waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent,"Share with"));
```

Comment: Hey Can I target for particular number for chat ?

Comment: without clicking on his name. Just using his phone number for eg : waIntent.putExtra(Intent.Extra_phoneNumber,9876543210);

Comment: i dont think so but if you tried it tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. WhatsApp allows the user to pick only one contact or pre-existing group at a time, and you cannot change that in any way.

Comment: yes thats right but the problem that i saw people do that but really need how....thanks for your respond