# Programatically Send WhatsApp to a list of Contacts without chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing a new App for android. I basically want to send a WhatsApp message to a list of contacts or numbers in my phone through my App. 
The important thing here, I would like to do this without using the chooser. In other words, my app will retrieve all my contacts, then it will make some filtering before sending a message to the list without having the user to manually use the Chooser.

And can I do this without Rooting my device?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774595/android-how-to-send-message-programatically-by-using-whats-app-we-chat

Answer (score 1):

For Share through any application...

```
public void sendAppMsg(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    String text = " message you want to share..";
    // change with required application package

    intent.setPackage("PACKAGE NAME OF THE APPLICATION");
    if (intent != null) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, text));
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "App not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Note : change *PACKAGE NAME OF THE APPLICATION as per your requirement like

Example : USE

Whatsapp: `intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");`

Linkedin: `intent.setPackage("com.linkedin.android");`

Twitter: `intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");`

Facebook: `intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");`

GooglePlus: `intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");`

Comment: Thanks Amarbir for the quick reply. Your code uses the Chooser which I emphasized I dont' want to use. My app will have a list of contacts and it needs to send one Whatsapp msg to all of them in the background without using the chooser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370965/how-to-broadcast-a-message-from-my-own-app-to-contacts-on-whatsapp